# How to deal with 'Package restore failed.! error?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have to install IdentityModel.OidcClient as a NuGet package and installation fails with

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'IdentityModel.OidcClient'.
NU1108 Cycle detected. IdentityModel.OidcClient -> IdentityModel.OidcClient (>= 3.1.2).
```

I cleared all the NuGet caches to no avail.
I made sure my class library has a target framework of .NET Standard 2.0 and the framework is supported by the IdentityModel version.

The second line from the error list is pointing at the first line of the project file (*.csproj) and it's content can be found below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I face the issue in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.8.4

How do I get the package installed?

Comment: What is the name of your project?

Comment: Thanks @GrigoryZhadko and yes, the project had the same name as the package I needed to install. I changed name and the installation went without a problem.